# Compute the joint probability of two "ordering" events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\{o_1, o_2, o_3, o_4\}$ be a set of objects, each one associated with a score $s(o_i)$. This score is uncertain, and thus described by means of a probability density function $f_i$. When a total ordering between the objects is required, the objects are ordered according to their scores. However, since the score is uncertain, a total ordering cannot be found univocally.

Let $\mathcal{O}_1 = \langle o_1 \prec o_2 \rangle$ and $\mathcal{O}_2 = \langle o_3 \prec o_4 \rangle$ be two ordering events, i.e., $\mathcal{O}_1$ is the event stating that the object $o_1$ is ranked higher than $o_2$ in a top-K ranking.

Since a total ordering is not found, each ordering event $\mathcal{O}_i$ is associated with a probability $\Pr(\mathcal{O}_i)$ of happening, which is computed by means of an integral:
$$
\Pr(\mathcal{O}_1) = \Pr(o_1 \prec o_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{x_2}^{+\infty} f_2(x_2)f_1(x_1)dx_1 dx_2
$$
where $f_1(x_1)$ and $f_2(x_2)$ are the PDFs of the objects score $s(o_1)$ and $s(o_2)$, respectively.

My objective is the one of computing $\Pr(\mathcal{O}_1 \land \mathcal{O}_2)$, i.e., the probability that $\mathcal{O}_1 = \langle o_1 \prec o_2 \rangle$ and $\mathcal{O}_2 = \langle o_3 \prec o_4 \rangle$ are both verified.

At first, I supposed that the two events were independent, which is not true (I guess). In fact, when the set of score probability distributions are all known, knowing that $o_1 \prec o_2$ may give us hints about the event $o_3 \prec o_4$. Thus, I guess that $\Pr(\mathcal{O}_1 \land \mathcal{O}_2) \neq \Pr(\mathcal{O}_1)\Pr(\mathcal{O}_2)$.

Which is the best way of computing this probability?

Comment: Are you saying the assignment of scores is not independent?  Otherwise, why are $\mathcal{O}_{1,2}$ not independent?

Comment: No, the assignment is independendent. But, suppose we have three objects o_1, o_2 and o_3. The PDFs are defined as follows: s(o_1)=[2 5], s(o_2)=[4 6], s(o_3) = [1 3]. You can verify that the only available orderings are: o_1 o_2 o_3, o_2 o_1 o_3, o_2 o_3 o_1. Thus, knowing that o_1 is ranked higher than o_2 or not, in this case, modifies the probability of o_1 of being ranked higher than o_3. If o_1 is ranked higher than o_2, in fact, Pr(o_1 \prec o_3) = 1. On the other hand, if o_1 is ranked lower than o_2, Pr(o_1 \prec o_3) < 1.